# Как узнать что прошел push

Tags: listener, parse.com, android, java

Я использую parse.com для отправки уведомлений на устройства. Код для подключения и библиотека взята с сайта. Уведомления приходят и показываются, но делает это их закрытая библиотека и когда она это делает не понятно. Так как уведомления сообщают о том что данные в расписании изменились, логично предположить что надо вызвать метод для обновления расписания, который у меня конечно уже есть, но как это сделать идей у меня нет.

Вот код для подключения в onCreate, класса который загружается при старте программы:

```
    Parse.initialize(this, "тут_длинный_ключ", "и_тут_тоже");
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, test.class);
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашел ответ на свой вопрос. Нужно было просто переопределить в манифесте ресивер из библиотеки, на свой.

```
<!--parse code-->
    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="ПЕРЕОПРЕДЕЛЯЕМ_ЭТОТ_РЕСИВЕР"
              android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="пакет проекта" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!--/parse code-->
```